# From a if condition in Java Bytecode, how to know which branch was taken( true/false)?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I have a small little program and have java bytecode for that,

```
test.passfail.pass_or_fail:19 ILOAD 0
test.passfail.pass_or_fail:19 ILOAD 1
test.passfail.pass_or_fail:19 IF_ICMPLE L0
test.passfail.pass_or_fail:20 ICONST_1
test.passfail.pass_or_fail:20 ISTORE 2
test.passfail.pass_or_fail:25 ILOAD 2
test.passfail.pass_or_fail:25 ICONST_1
test.passfail.pass_or_fail:25 IF_ICMPNE L2
test.passfail.pass_or_fail:25 ILOAD 0
test.passfail.pass_or_fail:25 BIPUSH 80
test.passfail.pass_or_fail:25 IF_ICMPLE L2
```

you can see conditions in lines 19 and 25, my question is what is the best way to know which branch was taken ( true or false ) seeing this trace?

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you're asking or what "line 25 is executed twice" means.

Comment: sorry for being unclear, I will edit the question again, so the question is if I collect a dynamic trace from the bytecode, how do I know which branch (true/false) was taken from a condition? So if I see test.passfail.pass_or_fail:19 IF_ICMPLE L0, how to know whether true of false branch is taken seeing the bytecode trace?

Comment: How do you “collect a dynamic trace” and what is the meaning of that output?

Comment: I used a slicing tool, and this is a slice based on some criterion.

Comment: That doesn’t explain the meaning of this output. An educated guess is that the numbers before the instructions are source code line numbers which is not helpful as conditionals can fit into a single line. Then, there are labels like L0 and L2 used in the instructions but not printed when encountered. Either, neither of these branches was taken or your tool doesn’t print the labels when encountering the corresponding code location. In the latter case, it would be impossible to tell for sure whether a branch has been taken from this output.